# window.onbeforeunload, window.unload, window.beforeunload functions are not working in IE and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {            
    // I need to call an API here but the window is closing
    // before making that HTTP call
    parent.API.LMSFinish("").then(function () { })
};
```

Is there any other way to call window.onbeforeunload function?

Comment: [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility) is definitely supported and works in the browsers you mentioned. It's more likely the problem is the code you've put within that event. However you haven't shown us that so no one can really help you

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
               parent.API.LMSFinish("").then(function () {
                })
            }  // In LMSFinish i am calling http hit. But it is not hitting that call

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for Firefox and IE:

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
    var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure to leave the page?';
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
});
```

UPDATE:

If your call is async the window will get closed and your call will not fire. You have to do a sync call in that event like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    url: '/clientarea/utils/record-time',
    data: 'teid=' + teid + '&t=' + t
});
```

Comment: Even I tried This.It is going in that function but before calling the http hit window is closing

Comment: Nice code snippet - this should be the accepted answer in point of view.